# How to get The QueryString Without EXEC and Print Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have other table **#table3** where the `@qur` will be stored and using that `@qur` i want to retrieve the data.
so it is possible to get data without set all query in other variable and execute this query directly.

this string of `@qur` not fixed it will different for different person.
and yes **i use sql server 2010**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Name] varchar(5), [DateVal] date, [TimeVal] time, [Item] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Name], [DateVal], [TimeVal], [Item])
VALUES
    ('Lisa', '2015-04-21', '10:20:06', 'Item1'),
    ('John', '2015-04-21', '10:25:30', 'Item2'),
    ('Peter', '2015-03-18', '13:35:32', 'Item3'),
    ('Ralf', '2015-04-03', '09:26:52', 'Item4')
;   

CREATE TABLE #Table2
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO #Table2
    ([ID],[Name])
VALUES
    (1,'Lisa' ),
    (2,'John' ),
    (3,'Peter'),
    (4,'Ralf')
;  





   DECLARE @qur VARCHAR(2000)='([Item] in (''Item1,Item2'')) and  [Name]=''Lisa'') '
       SELECT DateVal FROM #Table1 
       WHERE [Name] in (SELECT [Name] FROM #Table2)     
   AND @qur
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean SQL Server 2010?  Oh, and I'm pretty sure you're going to need either EXEC or sp_executesql there

Comment: i know to use Execute but it not look like i want. and we don't use to put direct variable query like this..

Comment: Would be best if you show table3, how you currently do what you want using `Exec` and `print`.

Comment: Query constructed at run-time = sp_executesql is necessary. There is no other way to do so. But if you only need to pass lists of arguments to where segment, you can construct appropriate tables and join them to the base query you use.

Comment: Jon Egerton. in third table where i am store the different  query for different situation where i use another query no. to manage that and that query will be defined at the registration time.  also using EXEC i ll get all query and store in single variable and then Execute that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can use the query bellow in SQLCMD mode:

```
:setvar qur  "and ([Item] in ('Item1','Item2')) and  [Name]='Lisa' "

SELECT DateVal FROM #Table1 
WHERE [Name] in (SELECT [Name] FROM #Table2) 
$(qur)
```

Comment: I don't know how to use this in sql server 2010

Comment: @gaborR It is still some kind of dynamic sql ;/. You can also write some code in .NET to avoid sp_executesql, but for me it is lying to yourself ;). Dynamic SQL is Dynamic SQL, regardless the way you run the query. However, vote up - I didn't know SQLCMD mode before ;).